# rbindlist data.tables with different number of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am wondering how do I rbindlist data tables with different number of columns, and filling up empty rows with NAs like rbind.fill

```
 DT1 <- data.table(A = 1:3)
 DT2 <- data.table(A  =4:5, B = letters[4:5])
 l <- list(DT1, DT2)
 rbindlist(l)
 #  Error in rbindlist(l) : 
 #   Item 2 has 2 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 1 columns
```

What I want to get is

```
   A B
1: 1 NA
2: 2 NA
3: 3 NA
4: 4 d
5: 5 e
```

Comment: Check out `rbind.fill {plyr}`

Comment: In this case you can use `merge(DT1, DT2, by="A", all=TRUE)`. But that only does the same as `rbind` because A is unique. Otherwise, you can still use `merge` if you add a unique id in each `data.table`.

Comment: The reason I posted this question was because I read that rbindlist is much faster than rbind. But perhaps rbind.fill is still the best way to do this. Also, isn't merge suppose to be very inefficient because it does a lot of checking?

Answer (score 10):

#### This feature is now implemented in [commit 1266 of v1.9.3](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=datatable&revision=1266). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=1266):

```
o  'rbindlist' gains 'use.names' and 'fill' arguments and is now implemented 
   entirely in C. Closes #5249    
  -> use.names by default is FALSE for backwards compatibility (doesn't bind by 
     names by default)
  -> rbind(...) now just calls rbindlist() internally, except that 'use.names' 
     is TRUE by default, for compatibility with base (and backwards compatibility).
  -> fill by default is FALSE. If fill is TRUE, use.names has to be TRUE.
  -> At least one item of the input list has to have non-null column names.
  -> Duplicate columns are bound in the order of occurrence, like base.
  -> Attributes that might exist in individual items would be lost in the bound result.
  -> Columns are coerced to the highest SEXPTYPE, if they are different, if/when possible.
  -> And incredibly fast ;).
  -> Documentation updated in much detail. Closes DR #5158.
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23923024/559784) for benchmarks.

---

### Examples:

1) Using `fill` argument of `rbindlist`:

```
DT1 <- data.table(x=1, y=2)
DT2 <- data.table(y=2, z=-1)

rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2), fill=TRUE)
#     x y  z
# 1:  1 2 NA
# 2: NA 2 -1
```

Note that when `fill=TRUE`, `use.names` should be `TRUE`.

---

2) Binding tables with duplicate names appropriately:

```
DT1 <- data.table(x=1, x=2, y=1, y=2)
DT2 <- data.table(y=3, y=-1, y=-2)

rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2), fill=TRUE)
#     x  x y  y  y
# 1:  1  2 1  2 NA
# 2: NA NA 3 -1 -2
```

---

3) It's not limited to just `data.tables`, but works on `data.frames` and `lists` as well:

```
DT1 <- data.table(x=1, y=2)
DT2 <- data.frame(y=2, z=-1)
DT3 <- list(z=10)

rbindlist(list(DT1,DT2,DT3), fill=TRUE)

#     x  y  z
# 1:  1  2 NA
# 2: NA  2 -1
# 3: NA NA 10
```

---

4) If you would like to bind just by names, you can set just `use.names=TRUE`, but not `fill`:

```
DT1 <- data.table(x=1, y=2)
DT2 <- data.table(y=1, x=2)

rbindlist(list(DT1,DT2), use.names=TRUE, fill=FALSE)
#    x y
# 1: 1 2
# 2: 2 1

DT1 <- data.table(x=1, y=2)
DT2 <- data.table(z=2, y=1)

# returns error when fill=FALSE but can't be bound without fill=TRUE
rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2), use.names=TRUE, fill=FALSE)
# Error in rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2), use.names = TRUE, fill = FALSE) : 
    # Answer requires 3 columns whereas one or more item(s) in the input 
    # list has only 2 columns. ...
```

---

5) The default is the same for backwards compatibility (`use.names=FALSE`, `fill=FALSE`):

```
DT1 <- data.table(x=1, y=2)
DT2 <- data.table(y=1, x=2)

rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2))

#    x y
# 1: 1 2
# 2: 1 2
```

HTH