# After doing bind_rows() and rbind() on same data.tables , identical() = FALSE?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rbind

Caveat: novice. I have several data.tables with millions of rows each, variables are mostly dates and factors. I was using rbindlist() to combine them [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind/). Yesterday, after breaking up the tables into smaller pieces vertically (instead of the current horizontal splicing), I was trying to understand rbind better (especially with fill = TRUE) and also tried bind_rows() and then tried to verify the results but identical() returned FALSE.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
DT1 <- data.table(a=1, b=2)
DT2 <- data.table(a=4, b=3)
DT_bindrows <- bind_rows(DT1,DT2)
DT_rbind <- rbind(DT1,DT2)
identical(DT_bindrows,DT_rbind)
 # [1] FALSE
```

Visually inspecting the results from bind_rows() and rbind() says they are indeed identical. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887217/difference-between-rbind-and-bind-rows-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605401/why-does-rbindlist-not-respect-column-names) (from where I adapted the example). My question: (a) what am I missing, and (b) if the number, names, and order of my columns is the same, should I be concerned that identical() = FALSE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `identical` checks for `attributes` which are not the same.  With `all.equal`, there is an option not to check the attributes (`check.attributes`)

```
all.equal(DT_bindrows, DT_rbind, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

If we check the `str` of both the datasets, it becomes clear

```
str(DT_bindrows)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 #variables:
# $ a: num  1 4
# $ b: num  2 3
str(DT_rbind)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 #variables:
# $ a: num  1 4
# $ b: num  2 3
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> # reference attribute
```

By assigning the attribute to NULL, the `identical` returns `TRUE`

```
attr(DT_rbind, ".internal.selfref") <- NULL
identical(DT_bindrows, DT_rbind)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I did not know of all.equal() - and so much else besides! Thank you for explaining it so well.

Comment: @armipunk Fyi, without that attribute, it may fail to be a properly functioning data.table. Eg, try `bind_rows(DT1,DT2)[, gah := 11]`, which on my system gives a warning about the missing attribute. Better not to do bind_rows unless it's supported through a data.table method in dtplyr, I guess https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr

Comment: @Frank Thank you - so far I have been pretty much sticking to data.table functions but as I start to mix things up a bit, good to know this.