# r: how to handle error in rbindlist probably related to "fill", when rbindlist is called via another package

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am having trouble with rbindlist called via the package `riskRegression`. It seems to be an issue with `fill = TRUE`, but I am not sure.

There are many topics related to similar [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605401/why-does-rbindlist-not-respect-column-names) with rbindlist, but it has not solved my issue.

**Questions:**
(1) Why does this specific error arise in this dataset/script, and
(2) How can it be fixed?

Data sample stored in `df` below.

I am quantifying the predictive performance of two independent cause-specific Cox regressions:

```
library(survival)
a_t7_n8_cmprsk <- coxph(Surv(event.tid, event == 1) ~ t7, 
                        x = TRUE, data = df)

a_t0_n8_cmprsk  <- coxph(Surv(event.tid, event == 1) ~ n8, 
                         x = TRUE, data = df)
```

The predictive performance is quantified using

```
library(riskRegression) 
u_n8_cmprsk <- Score(list("t7_n8" = a_t7_n8_cmprsk, "t0_n8" = a_t0_n8_cmprsk),
                     Hist(event.tid, event == 1) ~ 1,
                     data = df,
                     times = c(12, 30, 60), 
                     plots=c("cal"),
                     B = 100,
                     seed = 1,
                     split.method = "loob",
                     metrics = c("auc","brier"))
```

But - I receive the following error:

*Error in rbindlist(foreach::foreach(b = 1:B, .export = exports, .packages = "data.table",  : Item 79 has 2 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 9 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.*

Why and how to fix it?

```
df <- structure(list(t7 = c("pT1", "pT4a", "pT1", "pT4a", "pT1", "pT2", 
"pT2", "pT2", "pT3", "pT1", "pT2", "pT2", "pT1", "pT3", "pT3", 
"pT2", "pT2", "pT1", "pT1", "pT1", "pT4a", "pT1", "pT4a", "pT3", 
"pT1", "pT2", "pT2", "pT4a", "pT4a", "pT1", "pT4a", "pT2", "pT4a", 
"pT3", "pT1", "pT2", "pT4a", "pT1", "pT2", "pT1", "pT1", "pT2", 
"pT1", "pT2", "pT1", "pT2", "pT3", "pT4a", "pT2", "pT4a"), n8 = c("pN2b", 
"pN0", "pN0", "pN0", "pN0", "pN0", "pN0", "pN0", "pN3b", "pN0", 
"pN0", "pN1", "pN1", "pN3b", "pN0", "pN0", "pN1", "pN0", "pN0", 
"pN2b", "pN0", "pN3b", "pN3b", "pN3b", "pN0", "pN0", "pN2b", 
"pN3b", "pN1", "pN0", "pN0", "pN0", "pN3b", "pN3b", "pN2b", "pN0", 
"pN0", "pN0", "pN3b", "pN1", "pN0", "pN1", "pN3b", "pN0", "pN3b", 
"pN0", "pN3b", "pN0", "pN0", "pN1"), event.tid = c(82.4, 23.9, 
20.9, 0.4, 6.7, 124.2, 42.4, 38.8, 5.1, 6.5, 40.5, 15.3, 60.3, 
32.5, 62.9, 16.8, 14.8, 141, 63.4, 97.3, 13.2, 5.4, 134, 19.1, 
59.8, 179.5, 2.6, 130.7, 18.5, 40.5, 13.7, 52.9, 2.4, 9.3, 94.5, 
33.5, 79.3, 37.7, 12.7, 5.9, 98.5, 0.7, 17.5, 81.7, 24.4, 33.5, 
3.1, 3.1, 84.3, 7.9), event = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(262:446, names = c("262", 
"263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", 
"272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", 
"281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", 
"290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", 
"299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", 
"308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", 
"317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", 
"326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", 
"335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", 
"344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", 
"353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", 
"362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", 
"371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", 
"380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", 
"389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", 
"398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", 
"407", "408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", 
"416", "417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", 
"425", "426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", 
"434", "435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", 
"443", "444", "445", "446"), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Ask pkg developer to expose ... in his interface to pass extra arguments down to rbindlist. Or a much better way, fix your input to match columns rather than rely on auto filling with NAs.

Comment: Hi. I would much rather fix the input, but I simply does not know what cause the error. Where does the error occur in my input so that I can fix it? I mean, what columns does not match - I do not understand the error.

Comment: I don't know those interfaces so I don't know what they expect on input. Possibly a_t7_n8_cmprsk and a_t0_n8_cmprsk have a different length when they should have the same? Or you misuse the interface of Score? Try `rbindlist(list(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=3)))` to simulate the problem.