# fread() with dataset when there's missing column

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am using fread() to get data like this:

```
fread(data, select = c("col1", "col2", "missing", "col3"))
```

where column with the name of "missing" doesn't exist. fread() will automatically drop "missing" column and return dataset like this:

```
col1   col2   col3 
a      b      c
d      e      f
```

...

I am wondering if there is a way to change the result to:

```
col1   col2   missing  col3
a      b      NA       c
d      e      NA       f
```

Comment: You could consider adding the empty rows manually after reading the results.

Comment: I assume we are trying to read multiple files within a loop, then combine them when some might have mismatching column names, if so, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003717/is-there-any-efficient-way-than-rbind-filllist). We can just fread all in a *lapply* loop then *rbind* with *fill*.

Comment: @zx8754 that solved my problem perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged with `data.table` and `fread` but has attracted [a base R answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929416/3817004). Therefore, I felt obliged to post a `data.table` solution.

The OP wants to add a particular column at a specific place inside a `data.table` where this column appears to be missing. The OP seems to expect that the `select` parameter to `fread()` could be used for that purpose but `fread()` does print a

> Warning message:
> In fread("col1   col2   col3 \na      b      c\nd    e      f",  :
> Column name 'missing' not found in column name header (case sensitive), skipping.

So the missing column has to be added afterwards:

```
library(data.table)

# add column by reference
DT[, missing := NA][]
```

> ```
>    col1 col2 col3 missing
> 1:    a    b    c      NA
> 2:    d    e    f      NA
> ```

```
# rearrange column order
setcolorder(DT, c("col1", "col2", "missing", "col3"))[]
```

> ```
>    col1 col2 missing col3
> 1:    a    b      NA    c
> 2:    d    e      NA    f
> ```

Note that `data.table` excutes both operations *by reference*, i.e., it is not required to copy the whole object in order to add a single column or to change an attribute.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"col1   col2   col3 
a      b      c
d      e      f",
select = c("col1", "col2", "missing", "col3"))
```