# How do I append dataframes in a list?

Tags: r

I have this list:

```
list(structure(list(year = numeric(0), quarter = numeric(0), 
    Other = numeric(0), flow = character(0), country = character(0), 
    imfcode = integer(0), ISO3C = character(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(year = numeric(0), Other = numeric(0), flow = character(0), 
        country = character(0), 
 ISO3C = character(0)), row.names = integer(0), 
class = "data.frame"))
```

Each element of the list is a dataframe, I believe, although class() says that each element is actually a list of a dataframe. I wish to rbind all of these dataframes together. Is there an efficient way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: You can use `rbindlist(lst1)`  from `data.table` or `bind_rows(lst1)` from `dplyr`

Comment: This might help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003717/efficient-way-to-rbind-data-frames-with-different-columns

Comment: @akrun: holy! that's so efficient. I didn't know the existence of this function in the dplyr package. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lst1)
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst1)
```