# Add row to dataset for a range of columns[SOLVED]

Tags: r

I have the following tables:

```
df <- data.frame(DATE = c('07/01/2022', '08/01/2022'),
                 `0` = c(4, 4),
                 `1` = c(5, 3),
                  `2` = c(5,3), check.names = FALSE)
```

| Date | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/01/2022 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 08/01/2022 | 4 | 3 | 3 |

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = 2,
                 V2 = 4,
                 V3 = 5)
```

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |

I'm trying to add the values of V1, V2, and V3 below the last row of the first table, but only for columns 0:3. The output should look like this:

| Date | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/01/2022 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 08/01/2022 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
|  | 2 | 4 | 5 |

I tried rbind and bind_rows, but neither worked.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share reproducible examples. Also what did you try? Did you try `rbind()` for example?

Comment: Fixed that. I tried rbind and bind_rows

Comment: Change the column names on df2 to match df1 then see solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003717/efficient-way-to-rbind-data-frames-with-different-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rbind`, you can do,

```
rbind(df, 
      setNames(data.frame(DATE = '', df2), 
               names(df))
     )

        DATE X0 X1 X2
1 07/01/2022  4  5  5
2 08/01/2022  4  3  3
3             2  4  5
```

Comment: Convert to data.table, then we can just do: `rbind(DT1, DT2, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: How would I save this to the original datatable, so I could modify it further? For example, I tried manipulated_data[3:15] <- rbind(manipulated_data[3:15], setNames(data.frame(TOTAL = 'Weights', manipulated_data_numbers), names(manipulated_data[3:15]))) but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `rbindlist` from **data.table**

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(list(df1, cbind(Date = "", df2)), use.names=F)
         Date 0 1 2
1: 07/01/2022 4 5 5
2: 08/01/2022 4 3 3
3:            2 4 5
```